# How to get info from background_page to popup?

Tags: google-chrome, rss, google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest

I'm following the official Chrome Extension tutorial called `Chritter` where they fetch tweets from Twitter and place them into the extension. I'm trying to do similar except im trying to fetch items from an xml file.

**My XML**

```
<xml>

<item>
<title>Title 1</title>
<description>Description 1</description>
<duration>55:00</duration>
<published>28/01/2011</published>
</item>

<item>
<title>Title 2</title>
<description>Description 2</description>
<duration>55:00</duration>
<published>28/01/2011</published>
</item>

</xml>
```

**background.html**

```
<!--
To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

        <script type="text/javascript">
            var fetchFreq = 30000; // how often we fetch new items (30s)
            var req; // request object
            var unreadCount = 0; // how many unread items we have
            var items; // all currently fetched items

            getItems();
            //setInterval(getItems, fetchFreq);

            function getItems(){
                req = new XMLHttpRequest();
                req.open("GET", "http://urltoxml.com/xmlfile.xml", false);
                req.onload = processItems;
                req.send();
            }

            function processItems(){

                xmlDoc = req.responseXML;

                items = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("item");

                unreadCount += items.length;

                if (unreadCount > 0) {
                    chrome.browserAction.setBadgeBackgroundColor({
                        color: [255, 0, 0, 255]
                    });
                    chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({text: '' + unreadCount});
                }

                items = xmlDoc.concat(items);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
</html>
```

I don't know how to get the fetched items from the `background.html` and displayed onto the `popup.html` ?

**popup.html**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="popup.css" />
    <script src="util.js"></script>
    <script>
      var bg; // background page

      // timeline attributes
      var timeline;
      var template;
      var title;
      var link;
      var description;

      onload = setTimeout(init, 0); // workaround for http://crbug.com/24467

      // initialize timeline template
      function init() {
        chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({text: ''});
        bg = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage();
        bg.unreadCount = 0;

        timeline = document.getElementById('timeline');
        template = xpath('//ol[@id="template"]/li', document);
        title = xpath('//div[@class="text"]/span', title);
        content = xpath('//div[@class="text"]/span', template);

        update();
      }

     function update(){

     // how to do this ?
     // See Chritter example below with JSON,
     // except i want to it with xml ?

     }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="body">
      <ol id="timeline" />
    </div>
    <ol id="template">
      <li>
        <div class="text">
          <a></a>
          <span></span>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </body>
</html>
```

The way the `Chritter` extension does it only seems to work with JSON. Here is how they do it:

```
// update display
  function update() {
    var user;
    var url;
    var item;

    for (var i in bg.tweets) {
      user = bg.tweets[i].user;
      url = 'http://twitter.com/' + user.screen_name;

      // thumbnail
      link.title = user.name;
      link.href = openInNewTab(url);
      image.src = user.profile_image_url;
      image.alt = user.name;

      // text
      author.href = openInNewTab(url);
      author.innerHTML = user.name;
      content.innerHTML = linkify(bg.tweets[i].text);

      // copy node and update
      item = template.cloneNode(true);
      timeline.appendChild(item);
    }
  }
```

`Chritter` **background.html**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var fetchFreq = 30000; // how often we fetch new tweets (30s)
      var req; // request object
      var unreadCount = 0; // how many unread tweets we have
      var tweets; // all currently fetched tweets

      getTweets();
      setInterval(getTweets, fetchFreq);

      // fetch timeline from server
      function getTweets() {
        req = new XMLHttpRequest();
        req.open('GET', 'http://twitter.com/statuses/public_timeline.json');
        req.onload = processTweets;
        req.send();
      }

      // process new batch of tweets
      function processTweets() {
        var res = JSON.parse(req.responseText);
        unreadCount += res.length;

        if (unreadCount > 0) {
          chrome.browserAction.setBadgeBackgroundColor({
            color: [255, 0, 0, 255]
          });
          chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({text: '' + unreadCount});
        }

        tweets = res.concat(tweets);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
</html>
```

Any help much appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to access `items` var from a background page then:

```
var items = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().items;
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what the exact question is, but the general practice is to store the data from background page into localstorage and then access this data from the popup page.

http://www.rajdeepd.com/articles/chrome/localstrg/LocalStorageSample.htm

Comment: There's no need to store things in local storage unless you need them to persist between browser sessions. The background page and its variables are directly accessible by all extension scripts aside from content scripts.